# Upload csv file from a custom admin form issue

Tags: magento2.4, file-upload

This is my fieldset from the uicomponent form:

```
<fieldset name="image_form_fieldset">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Form</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
    <field name="file">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string">File</item>
                <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">fileUploader</item>
                <item name="source" xsi:type="string">file</item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">15</item>
                <item name="uploaderConfig" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="url" xsi:type="url" path="regenerate/image/file"/>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </field>
</fieldset>
```

This is my controller for the `regenerate/image/file` part:

```
use Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException;
use Magento\Framework\Filesystem;
use Magento\MediaStorage\Model\File\UploaderFactory;
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;
use Magento\Framework\UrlInterface;
use Magento\Backend\App\Action;

class File extends Action {

    /**
     * @var UploaderFactory
     */
    protected $uploaderFactory;

    /**
     * @var Filesystem\Directory\WriteInterface
     */
    protected $mediaDirectory;

    /**
     * @var StoreManagerInterface
     */
    protected $storeManager;

    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        UploaderFactory $uploaderFactory,
        Filesystem $filesystem,
        StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
    )
    {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->uploaderFactory = $uploaderFactory;
        $this->mediaDirectory = $filesystem->getDirectoryWrite(\Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList::MEDIA);
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $jsonResult = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_JSON);
        try {
            $fileUploader = $this->uploaderFactory->create(['fileId' => 'file']);
            $fileUploader->setAllowedExtensions(['csv']);
            $fileUploader->setAllowRenameFiles(true);
            $fileUploader->setAllowCreateFolders(true);
            $fileUploader->setFilesDispersion(false);
            $fileUploader->validateFile();
            $result = $fileUploader->save($this->mediaDirectory->getAbsolutePath('tmp/imageUploader/images'));
            $result['url'] = $this->storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl(UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA) . 'regenerate_images/';
            return $jsonResult->setData($result);
        } catch (LocalizedException $e) {
            return $jsonResult->setData(['errorcode' => 0, 'error' => $e->getMessage()]);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            error_log($e->getMessage());
            error_log($e->getTraceAsString());
            return $jsonResult->setData(['errorcode' => 0, 'error' => __('An error occurred, please try again later.'. $e->getMessage())]);
        }
    }
}
```

My code is failing at this part: `$fileUploader = $this->uploaderFactory->create(['fileId' => 'file']);`. Getting this error message:

```
An error occurred, please try again later.Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in ../vendor/magento/framework/File/Uploader.php on line 226
```

Any idea why ? and how can I fix this. I just want to upload a csv file in the media folder.

Thanks

Comment: Please specify Magento version and please confirm you don't have any preferences for `\Magento\MediaStorage\Model\File\Uploader`. Based on line`$fileUploader->validate();` you have a some customization for `Uploader`. Except `validate` - provided code should work with original uploader.

Comment: H @VictorTihonchuk it is about magento 2.4.3-p1. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem mainly was because of this part:

```
['fileId' => 'file']
```

It didn't match with my input value name defined in the UI Component.  I will leave here all of the code, maybe it will help someone in the future:

From: `app/code/Vendor/Products/view/adminhtml/layout/regenerate_image_index.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="admin-2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <title>Regenerate Image Cache</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <uiComponent name="fileupload_form"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

From: `app/code/Vendor/Products/view/adminhtml/ui_component/fileupload_form.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Ui/etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">fileupload_form.fileupload_form_data_source</item>
            <item name="deps" xsi:type="string">fileupload_form.fileupload_form_data_source</item>
        </item>
        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Form</item>
        <item name="layout" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="type" xsi:type="string">tabs</item>
        </item>
        <item name="buttons" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="save" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="name" xsi:type="string">save</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Upload CSV file</item>
                <item name="class" xsi:type="string">save primary</item>
            </item>
        </item>
    </argument>

    <dataSource name="fileupload_form_data_source">
        <argument name="dataProvider" xsi:type="configurableObject">
            <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">Vendor\Products\Model\DataProvider</argument>
            <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">fileupload_form_data_source</argument>
            <argument name="primaryFieldName" xsi:type="string">entity_id</argument>
            <argument name="requestFieldName" xsi:type="string">id</argument>
        </argument>
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/provider</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </dataSource>

    <fieldset name="fileupload_form">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Form</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <field name="file">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string">File</item>
                    <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">fileUploader</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">file</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">15</item>
                    <item name="uploaderConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="url" xsi:type="url" path="regenerate/image/file"/>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

From my controller:  `app/code/Vendor/Products/Controller/Adminhtml/Image/File.php` :

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Products\Controller\Adminhtml\Image;

use Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException;
use Magento\Framework\Filesystem;
use Magento\MediaStorage\Model\File\UploaderFactory;
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;
use Magento\Backend\App\Action;
use Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList;
use Exception;

class File extends Action {

    /**
     * @var Filesystem
     */
    protected $fileSystem;

    /**
     * @var UploaderFactory
     */
    protected $uploaderFactory;

    /**
     * @var Filesystem\Directory\WriteInterface
     */
    protected $mediaDirectory;

    /**
     * @var StoreManagerInterface
     */
    protected $storeManager;

    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        UploaderFactory $uploaderFactory,
        Filesystem $filesystem,
        StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        Filesystem $fileSystem
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->uploaderFactory = $uploaderFactory;
        $this->mediaDirectory = $filesystem->getDirectoryWrite(DirectoryList::MEDIA);
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->fileSystem = $fileSystem;
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $jsonResult = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_JSON);
        try {
            $fileUploader = $this->uploaderFactory->create([
                'fileId' => 'fileupload_form[file]'
            ]);
            $fileUploader->setAllowedExtensions(['csv']);
            $fileUploader->setAllowRenameFiles(true);
            $fileUploader->setAllowCreateFolders(true);
            $fileUploader->setFilesDispersion(false);

            $data = $fileUploader->save($this->mediaDirectory->getAbsolutePath('regenerate_images'));

            return $jsonResult->setData($data);

        } catch (LocalizedException|Exception $error) {
            return $jsonResult->setData(['errorcode' => 0, 'error' => $error->getMessage()]);
        }
    }
}
```

Good luck!